# remove .zprofile:1: no such file or directory: from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, apple-m1

Every time I open terminal I get:

```bash
/Users/me/.zprofile:1: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/me/.zprofile:2: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

Can someone help how to remove this?

Answer (score 1):

`.zprofile` is generally used as a profile config file for Z shell. In OSX if you've installed brew using `Rosetta` terminal the exec location would be most likely in `/usr/local/bin/brew`. You can replace `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew` with this location or you can just check it using `which brew` to get the bin location of homebrew and replace it in `.zprofile` file.